# Store downloaded file in database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

After I charge customer for downloaded file I need to store that file in a table in the database.
What I am trying now is not working. I think my query is wrong, etc. This is part of a tutorial I am extending [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/selling-downloads-stripe-laravel/) The tutorial uses sessions and I need it converted to just a check if the id of user is equal to authenticated user in database.

```
Route::post('/buy/{id}', function($id)
{
/*1. check and see if user is logged in before trying to buy*/

if(Auth::check()) {


    Stripe::setApiKey(Config::get('laravel-stripe::stripe.api_key'));

    //$download = new Download;
    $download = Download::find($id);
    //dd($download);
    //stripeToken is form name, injected into form by js
    $token = Input::get('stripeToken');


    /* 2. If user is logged in charge the card*/
    try {
        $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
            "amount" => $download->price,
            "currency" => "gbp",
            "card" => $token,
            "description" => 'Order: ' . $download->name)
        );


        // If we get this far, we've charged the user successfully

        /* 3.Insert file user downloaded into database purchase table
        only if user id is equal to auth id in users table*/

        $user = DB::table('users')
            ->where('id', 'Auth::user()->id')
            ->exists();

        //dd($user);



        //$download->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->exist;



        return Redirect::to('confirmed', '$download');

    } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {
        // Payment failed
        return Redirect::to('buy/'.$id)->with('message', 'Your payment has failed.');       
    }

}

});
```

Comment: 'Is not working' does not say much, please post errors and model. Also, if(Auth::user()->id == $id){*}.